# Umbraco 8 + React - How to access image

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco8

Trying to pull an image from Umbraco and display it using React.

I can pull all the text by doing this for example -

`{String(this.props.data['carouselUnderImageText'])}
 {String(this.props.data['carouselLink'])}`

But when doing an image -

`<img src={this.props.data["carouselImage"]}` or `<img src={String(this.props.data["carouselImage"])} />`

Those two won't work, it seems to return me the url `umb://media/8990dd19cfb746e0bea4baec5df20d01`

Any ideas on how to solve this? I have not found enough documentation to fix this issue when using Umbraco with React.

**If there is anything else I can show in order to help answer this question just put it in the comments and I will update the question.**

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure this is React related. Maybe you have to do something [like this](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/89243-getting-medias-url-from-umbracos-uid)?

Comment: @Tholle it seems to be a bit different when trying to render it with React, thanks for that though, il look into it.

Comment: The property value you are seeing is the ID (or, as Umbraco calls it, UDI) of the image. I don&#39;t know much about React, but you&#39;ll need to look up the actual image properties via the UDI somehow. In a controller, I&#39;d guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IPublishedContent of the image file by using the TypedMedia function in the Umbraco Helper, you can then access the images URL to be passed through to react.

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
Udi.TryParse(carouselImage, out var carouselImageUdi); // this parses the umb://media string into a UDI to be used in TypedMedia.
var imageUrl = umbracoHelper.TypedMedia(carouselImageUdi).Url;
```